# Deleting and replacing an object pointer in the middle of a CAtlArray

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, atl

I have a CAtlArray that holds object pointers defined like

```
CAtlArray<MyClass*> objPtrArray;
```

There are conditions where the object needs to be updated and rather than copy the members, I would prefer to just update the pointer. Basically, this happens in the update:

```
objPtryArray.SetAt( i, newObj );
```

My first question is do I need to delete the pointer that used to live in i (yes, it was allocated with new)? My intuition says yes, but when I try to do that the program crashes.
I have tried many variations of the following:

```
delete objPtrArray[i];
objPtrArray.SetAt( i, newObj );
```

Another attempt was:

```
MyClass *tmpObj;
tmpObj = objPtrArray[i];
objPtrArray.SetAt( i, newObj );
delete tmpObj;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I should clarify. The program doesn't actually crash at the time of the pointer replacement. If I don't delete the old pointer, it is fine and the object updates. However, if I delete the old pointer I get strange behavior. For example, one of the object's member char arrays might go from "Hello" to a strange character like "Ä". The program will often then crash a few minutes later.

Additionally, there are actually more than one CAtlArray of the same object pointers - one that is the main data array and the others are used for virtual list views. I do update the virtual list array using SetAt, too.

UPDATE:

Ok, the issue really had nothing to do with CAtlArray. One of the pointers I was trying to update was actually pointing to the old pointer in a different array (to manage virtual list view) so this was the root of the problem. Consequently, deleting the old pointer would actually delete the new pointer as well. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

`CAtlArray` is array of something. This container never analyze type of object, so it shouldn't free memory if you replace one pointer by another one. You can find it in it's source code:

```
inline void CAtlArray< E, ETraits >::SetAt( size_t iElement, INARGTYPE element )
{
    ATLASSERT( iElement < m_nSize );
    m_pData[iElement] = element;
}
```

I.e., if you are using this container for pointers, you have to delete replaced object.

So, it is strange, that you have this crash. Are you sure the problem is not in line `objPtrArray[i]` (may be `i` is out of range)? It is better to try to debug this bug, since you can easely reproduce it. Please tell us, what is reason of crash.

Comment: I should clarify. The program doesn't actually crash at the time of the pointer replacement. If I don't delete the old pointer, it is fine and the object updates. However, if I delete the old pointer I get strange behavior. For example, one of the object's member char arrays might go from "Hello" to a strange character like "Ä". The program will often then crash a few minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

The array holds the pointers without accessing objects referenced by them. This means that when those objects become invalid (esp. after their destruction) and the array still holds their pointers, this is not immediately the problem. You are not going to get any crash until you read the pointer - for some reason - back from the collection and attempt to access referenced object, which is no longer in good standing.

That is, you don't need to delete pointers from the collection to avoid crashes, but if your code reads the pointers elsewhere with certain logic around referenced objects, then you are interested in removing pointers timely ([`CAtlArray::RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xk5x537.aspx)) to prevent dealing with deleted objects.